# The Aim 9 missile mounted on the left side spin in the same direction as right side mounted after launching?

Tags: aerodynamics, missiles

When the AIM 9 sidewinder missile is fired the spin is in the same direction?

Comment: Are you asking whether there are two versions of the missile- a left version and a right version?

Comment: Yes , but not two versions ,just the fins orientations when they are mounted on left side or right side of the aircraft

Comment: @George Geo - No, there is no different fin orientation. Add in a 3rd config, underwing launchers. ex: Station 2 & 8 on an F-16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add something to @WPNSGuy answer.

A spin is normally imparted to a projectile in order to improve its stability via both an aerodynamic and a gyroscopic effect. Stability here means that the projectile remains more or less fixed on the trajectory given when fired.

AIM-9, like other weapons, works in a different way: it (more or less continually) tracks its target and modify its trajectory consequently. Imparting a spin in order to fix its trajectory would therefore be against its own mission.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers , the question came because I seen an documentary about dogfights in Israel and missile are show that they are spinning in flight after gaining speed

Comment: @GeorgeGeo  Some missiles do; the SA-7 (a pretty old missile now, but revolutionary when it was first introduced) has a distinctive corkscrew flightpath, due to the way its seeker works.  More modern missiles, not as much, because that sort of flightpath is aerodynamically less efficient.  Note that depending on how it is produced, a documentary may use CGI "footage" of aircraft and missiles, which is no more realistic than the assumptions programmed into the software used to generate it.

Comment: @RalphJ: oh, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/9K32_Strela-2) this was due to a limitation in the design of the infrared seeker which had a blind spot just in its middle. As soon as the missile was pointing just straight against its target it became "blind" and had to steer  away to regain sight of the target.

Answer (score 10):

The missile does what it wants to do. No spin is imparted by the missile rail as it leaves, from either side.

Indeed, unlike a bullet, an AIM-9 is not spin stabilized. It does not spin (or *tries* not to spin). The rollerons on the rear fins counteract any roll.

> A rolleron is a type of aileron used for rockets and used to provide
> passive stabilization against rotation. While most commonly used to
> stablize against roll, it can also be used for counteracting yaw and
> pitch as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolleron

Comment: This is clearly the best answer. It’s beyond me why it was not selected. :-(

Comment: @Jim: this is actually the **only** answer so far, mine is just an addendum, as clearly specified at its beginning. If you are unhappy with GeorgeGeo choice write a comment under its question and discuss the matter with him.